# How to link slidy presentation to blogdown post

Tags: r, r-markdown, blogdown, slidy

I followed the advice in the `blogdown` book, put my `.Rmd` file in the `static` directory and used `R/build.R` to render a slidy presentation. I'm wondering how I can now link or publish the `html` file in a blog post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a file `static/foo/bar.html`, its URL will be `/foo/bar.html`, as I have mentioned in the very first paragraph in [Section 2.7](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/static-files.html) (which you said you had read).

You can also study the Markdown source documents of the example I mentioned in Section 2.7: https://github.com/yihui/blogdown-static

Note that you cannot publish these HTML files as blog posts. You can only link to them in the body of your blog posts.

Comment: Thanks, Yihui. I was leaving the forward slash out by mistake.